# How to Make a Banner Image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, banner

I have started developing my first website. I have run into an issue though - I can't figure out how to make a "Banner Image"!

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
Since I am a beginner in CSS, how would I make a simple version of this?

Comment: :D well... using Bootstrap :) Also what's a "`banner image`"? this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image ? You're talking about *my first website*, right?

Comment: There is no image in the link you posted!

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Yes, my first website! And by Banner Image, I am referring to the Purple space, with the Bootstraps logo, Description, and Download Now Button. The area in [This](http://i.imgur.com/A4VWVQv.png?1) Image that is boxed in Green is what I am referring to.

Comment: OK, but what HTML+CSS code have you tried so far?? Take a DIV, set a height, put a background image, set it as `background: url(bg.jpg) 50% / cover;` put inside that DIV some text, adn buttons and set to that DIV `text-align:center;` and you're done. Seems like you've tried nothing yet to me...

Comment: @Parker What? That's not a link

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It's not even that complicated really. just use `col-xs-12 text-center` as the div class.

Comment: @Parker Yes, but the site he linked to doesn't contain an image, it's text only, try it getbootstrap.com

Comment: @Parker A screenshot of a site with no images!

Comment: I think OP is just asking how to make a header like in the example, I agree it's not technically an image - I see what you mean now

Comment: @DavidG I never used bootstrap cause when you know HTML and CSS that's all it takes: http://jsfiddle.net/j2vz1m93/ ;) (P.S. i just saved some bandwith)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Totally agree HTML/CSS should be learned, but if you want to make a fully responsive website very quickly, I highly recommend Bootstrap.

Comment: @DavidG I know and agree :D (but really more and more people are asking strange bootstrap questions on SO like it's... I don't know...)

Comment: @DavidG I was only using Bootstraps as an example. I currently have no intention on using the Framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways using which you can create a banner image, the easy way and the not-so-difficult way.

**The Easy Way:**

Create a banner image using an image editing software like Photoshop and then use that image as a `background-image` on a `<div>`. Like this:

```css
#bannerimage {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://s30.postimg.org/x0ne0p5wx/bootsrap.png);
  height: 405px;
  background-color: purple;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerimage"></div>
```

**The Not-So-Difficult Way:**

You will need to convert the banner design into HTML and style it using CSS. For example, let's take into account that purple bootstrap banner. It has a large purple background and all the text is added on it and then styled using CSS. You can do that like this:

```css
#header {
    background: #664c8f;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 100px
}
h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
}
a#download {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.</h1><a href="#" id="download">Download</a>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `width: 1349px;` but why??

Comment: @rokoc.buljan I've modified that part of my code, please check.

Comment: Why not make it responsive using `background: url(bg.jpg) 50% / cover;` and just some text-align: center;

Comment: @rokoc.buljan There are many possibilities to create a banner image  (like the one whichy you've mentioned above) as you already know but I just wanted to mention an easy method, i.e. use a background-image, and a little complicated method which is to code it using HTML and CSS.

Comment: OK, but why suggesting to set `width:100%` to a DIV element if it's already taking the available space being a block-level element? Also : http://jsfiddle.net/j2vz1m93/

Comment: How would I be able to do "The Not-So-Difficult Way" Without using the Bootstrap stylesheet?

Comment: @xvxm4tthewxvx Here's an example to do that without the Bootstrap stylesheet: http://jsfiddle.net/ymb0v6nL/7/. I've also edited my main answer.

Comment: @FahadHasan Thank you!!! Your "Not-So-Difficult Way" helped alot!!! And another special thanks to Roko Buljan too!

Comment: Good answer. Also kudos for helping a beginner rather than voting down. One thing though: only use background image if there's absolutely no useful (only decorative) content in the image. In all other cases use a regular image (<img ...>) with a descriptive alt-text. Don't treat the disabled as if they are not important! :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#bannerimage {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://s30.postimg.org/x0ne0p5wx/bootsrap.png);
  height: 405px;
  background-color: purple;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerimage"></div>
```